# Index not used for Mongodb find query

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb

I am trying to have full text search on my database. I am using MongoDb, TS and node js. My problem is the following:
I am unit testing and my test to find a text string in the index keeps failing. The index gets created using the wildcard syntax.
However when using the find()-function I get an empty object or undefined back, not the result I am expecting.

Here is some of my code:

This is the function used for creating the index and searching using full text.

```
async createIndexForSearch() {
    const itemCollection: Collection<Item> = this.db.collection<Item>(
      this.collectionName
    );
    const index = await itemCollection.createIndex(
      {"**": "text" }, { default_language: 'none'}
    );
   
    return index;
  }

  async findItems(searchText: string): Promise<any[]> {
    const itemCollection: Collection<Item> = this.db.collection<Item>(
      this.collectionName
    );

    let items: any = [];
    let item = await itemCollection.find();
    // console.log('collection', item);
    let query = { $text: { $search: searchText}};
    let sort = { score: { $meta: "textScore" } };
    // console.log(query);

    const results = {
      _id: 0,
      title: 1,
      location: 1,
      itemNr: 1,
      loanState: 1
    };
    
    items = await itemCollection.find(query).sort(sort).project(results).toArray();
   
    console.log(itemCollection);
    return items;
  }
```

This is my test case:

```
 it('should create an index and make it searchable', async () => {
    const { item1, item2, item3} = await createSampleItems();
    const indexCreated = await service.createIndexForSearch();


    let searchstring = 'Test';
    let itemsRetrieved = await service.findItems(searchstring);


    expect(itemsRetrieved.length).toBe(1);
  })
```

createSampleItems() just fills a few items into the db.

I cannot figure out which puzzle piece I am missing to be able to do the full text search and have after googling and reading the documentation not found out why it does not work.

If you could show me where my mistake is and show me the correct syntax, that would be very nice of you.

I am also not using mongoose.

Comment: What do the sample items look like?

Comment: A typical mongodb document with title, itemnr, _id, description and status of the item. Eg item = { _id: xyz, title: 'lorem ipsum', itemnr: '007', description: ' sit dolor amet', status: active}. All strings should be searchable.

Comment: In that sample the document, the word "Test" doesn't appear, what should the search be returning?

Comment: If I was searching for 'lorem' it should return the item. I forgot to add test in the example, my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was:
`const index = await itemCollection.createIndex( {"**": "text" }, { default_language: 'none'} );`
Where `{"**": "text" }` should be `{"$**": "text" }`.

Comment: You can put your code in code block so it will look more nice. Like for Javascript
```js
Code
```